# After install 'spree_reviews' get error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, spree

i'm beginer Rails. when i install gem 'spree_reviews' in spree-contrib. after **install success** get error:

```
Showing C:/Bitnami/rubystack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/spree-ac4d1d019026/frontend/app/views/spree/shared/_head.html.erb where line #7 raised:

wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)

Trace of template inclusion: C:/Bitnami/rubystack/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/spree-ac4d1d019026/frontend/app/views/spree/layouts/spree_application.html.erb
```

`

Comment: when you restart server this error appear?

Comment: it error after i install this gem.

Comment: i think it added some migration did you run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: i checked success. it wrong in all.js `//= require spree/frontend/my //= require spree/frontend/spree_reviews` in one line.